# Get user record in relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have 3 tables:

1. `users` table
2. `posts` table (users can have many posts)
3. `likes` table (works in the same way that Facebook likes do)

I have the following relationships:

**User.php**:

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

**Post.php**:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

public function likes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
}
```

**Like.php**:

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}
```

To get all posts, I do:

```
$posts = Post::with('likes')
    ->get();
```

However, this returns *all* likes associated with the post (which I don't want). What I need to be able to do is check if the *logged in user* has liked each post.

For example, in my view, I have:

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    // check if logged in user liked the $post
@endforeach
```

How can I modify my code so that I can check if the user has liked each post and **how can I do this by simply adding a new relationship**?

Comment: isn't there relation between like and user?

Comment: @SanzeebAryal There is not, but how would that help?

Comment: to know who has liked the post.

Comment: you should take a look at laracasts.com he has a complete series about a facebook like app and also some videos about likes in laravel

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a relationship between users and likes

**User Model**

```
public function likes() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
}
```

**Like Model**

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

**Post Model**

```
public function isLiked() {
    return (bool) $this->likes()->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->first(); 
    // Will return true if liked by the logged in user
}
```

Now you can use it like that:

```
if ( $post->isLiked() ) {
    // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you have make relation between Post with Likes, and Post with User models

So... in Post model create public function, I think you have fields like *post_id* and *user_id*, to keep the likes.

**Post Model:**

```
public function likes()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Like', 'post_id);
}
```

after that in your controller make query to get the posts

**Post Controller**

```
 $post = Post::all();
```

and in the template, you can check if user_id is in this post like

**Post View**

```
foreach($post as $p) {
  if($logged_user_id === $p->like()->user_id) {
    echo 'liked';
  } else {
   echo 'not liked';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you, (step-1)

```
    $post = Post::with(['Like.User' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('users.id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
    }])->get();
```

Note:- users is table name.
  It will give all post and all like with user who is log in.

Another one solution, it will return all post with particular likes (likes by auth user) with user.  (step-2)

```
     foreach ($post as $item) {
        $like = $item->Like;
        foreach ($like as $key => $user){
            if(count($user->User) == 0){
                unset($like[$key]);
            }
        }
    }
```

The result will be for step 1:-

```
     [
       {
         "post" : "details",
         "like" : [ { 
                    "post_id" : 1,
                    "user_id" : 1 },
                    { 
                    "post_id" : 1,
                    "user_id" : null }],
       {
         "post" : "details",
         "like" : [] }
     ]
```

The result will be for step 2:-

```
     [
       {
         "post" : "details",
         "like" : [ { 
                    "post_id" : 1,
                    "user_id" : 1 }],
       {
         "post" : "details",
         "like" : []  }
     ]
```

The result keywords are assumption and the expectation is user_id in post and like tables, post_id in like table.